# Linking Hyperlinks in a Word Document to a corresponding document in a excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

To keep it simple I have several hundred word documents for clients which list templates used for those clients. I need to hyperlink each mention of a template in every document to its corresponding template document, which are all stored in a template folder.

I have a excel spread sheet with 2 columns. The 1st being the name of the template, the 2nd being a hyperlink to that template in the relevant folder. 
Below is the script I have created but I am having issues getting it to hyperlink the text, I have tried the code written here with some changed to search and replace with my variable but it makes them all the same hyperlink. https://superuser.com/a/1010293

I am struggling to find another way to do this based on my current knowledge of VBA.

Below is my current code which carries out the whole task.

```
    Public strArray() As String
    Public LinkArray() As String
    Public TotalRows As Long

Sub Hyperlink()
Dim file
Dim path As String
Dim FilenameWaterMark As String

Call OpenExcelFile

i = 1
For i = 1 To TotalRows

'here I need the document to look through while searching for strarray(I) 
'and make that string a hyperlink to linkarray(I) 
Next


ActiveDocument.Save

End Sub

Sub OpenExcelFile()
'Variables

    Dim i, x As Long
    Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim oWB As Workbook
     i = 1
'Opening Excel Sheet
    Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
    Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("H:\DCTEST\Templates\DOCS.xlsx")
    oExcel.Visible = True

'Counts Number of Rows in Sheet
    TotalRows = Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim strArray(1 To TotalRows)
    ReDim LinkArray(1 To TotalRows)

'Assigns each cell in Column A to an Array
    For i = 1 To TotalRows
        strArray(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value
    Next

'searches for hyperlink
    For i = 1 To TotalRows
        LinkArray(i) = Cells(i, 2).Value
    Next

oExcel.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working myself. Below is the full code.

```
Dim strArray() As String
    Dim LinkArray() As String
    Dim TotalRows As Long

Private Sub DOCUMENT_OPEN()
Dim file
Dim path As String
Dim FilenameWaterMark As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim SearchString As String
Dim EndString As String
Dim Id As String
Dim Link As String

Call OpenExcelFile

i = 1
For i = 1 To TotalRows


Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range
SearchString = strArray(i)
    With Rng.Find
    .MatchWildcards = False
        Do While .Execute(findText:=SearchString, Forward:=False, MatchWholeWord:=True) = True
            Rng.MoveStartUntil (strArray(i))
            Rng.MoveEndUntil ("")
            Link = LinkArray(i)

                ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Rng, _
                Address:=Link, _
                SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=Rng.Text
                Rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart


        Loop
    End With
Next


ActiveDocument.Save

End Sub

Sub OpenExcelFile()
'Variables

    Dim i, x As Long
    Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim oWB As Workbook
     i = 1
'Opening Excel Sheet
    Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
    Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("H:\DCTEST\Templates\DOCS.xlsx")
    oExcel.Visible = False

'Counts Number of Rows in Sheet
    TotalRows = Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim strArray(1 To TotalRows)
    ReDim LinkArray(1 To TotalRows)

'Assigns each cell in Column A to an Array
    For i = 1 To TotalRows
        strArray(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value
    Next

'searches for hyperlink
    For i = 1 To TotalRows
        LinkArray(i) = Cells(i, 2).Value
    Next

oExcel.Quit

End Sub
```

This runs when the document is open and links all mentions of a template to its document in the template folder.